# Constructive proof of the Cauchy Schwarz inequality

Tags: analysis, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, constructive-mathematics

The famous CS inequality states

$$
\left| \left< x , y \right>\right|
  \le \left\| x \right\| \cdot \left\| y \right\|
$$

for $x,y$ in an inner product space $X$ over $\mathbb{K}$. Every proof I found involves some kind of case distinction; namely one may use w.l.o.g $\Vert x \Vert, \Vert y \Vert > 0$ since the inequality is trivial otherwise. However, I was looking for a constructive proof (i.e. without using the law of excluded middle) for the inequality.

I will add some remarks to the question.

1) Law of excluded middle: This axiom states that $A \vee \neg  A$ is true. This is not considered an axiom in constructive mathematics. One might interpret this in the following way: Indirect proofs are not allowed. However, I find this not completely accurate. Precisely the implication $A \rightarrow \neg \neg A$ is true in constructive mathematics; the implication $ \neg \neg A \rightarrow A$ not in gerneral.

2) The definition of an inner product is the same as in "classical" mathematics.

3) The norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is given by $\Vert x \Vert = \sqrt{\langle x, x\rangle }$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'constructive' here? Cauchy-Schwarz doesn't assert the existence of anything, so there's nothing to construct.

Comment: It's actually for $x,y$ in an inner product space.

Comment: I feel a bit sorry for Diamir. Every time Diamir posts a question to [tag:constructive-mathematics], someone either gives a non-constructive proof or asks what "constructive" means despite Diamir asking for a constructive proof in the title, body, and via tags and explicitly specifying what "constructive" means in this case. On the other hand, Diamir's questions are often ambiguous since they don't provide definitions for the concepts being used. Since classically equivalent definitions are not necessarily constructively equivalent, this really matters.

Comment: Derek, no need for the passive aggression. I checked Wikipedia before making my comment, and its page on "constructive proof" agrees with my definition. As you note, the question is not clearly asked.

Comment: @dbx It's not passive aggression. I felt like saying the same thing the last time Diamir asked a question. That said, to *actually* directly respond to you: if you don't know what "constructive" means or at least how Diamir is using it, why did you post an answer?

Comment: @DerekElkins I realize that my questions are not clearly formulated. I will try to improve this in the future. However, the only classification of constructive mathematics (at least the way I am using it) is that the law of excluded middle is not considered an axiom. I realize that this might be confusing since one usually does not actually realize which exact axiom one is using in every step of a proof.

Comment: @DerekElkins I answered because I *do* know what a constructive proof is, in the usual sense of the term. As I explained above.

Comment: @Diamir Your question isn't unclear (to me) because of your definition of "constructive". Short of specifying a specific constructive logic, I'm really not sure what more you could do to communicate what you mean by "constructive". People seem to consistently ignore either that you said "constructive" at all or that you and the tag give a definition of "constructive". The unclarity is that traditional definitions of particular concepts, e.g. the real numbers, are often bad or ambiguous definitions constructively, e.g. Dedekind reals and Cauchy reals are not the same thing constructively.

Comment: @Diamir   Here's an idea that I just thought of that might help. Maybe say something like "a proof in intuitionistic logic" rather than "a constructive proof". Sure, someone might think you intend to allow some of the anti-classical axioms of Intuitionism, but at least that person would be somewhat knowledgeable about non-classical logics and would understand if you clarified that you wanted to restrict to Bishop-style constructivism.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:**

The initial answer was written in a short time after the posted question. The initial question did not - for my glasses - put enough accent on the fact that we are working in [Constructive analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_analysis). (The tag constructive-mathematics did not even capture my attention on its last place where it stayed.) So the question was explicitly:

> The famous CS inequality states $$ \vert \langle x , y \rangle \vert \le \Vert x \Vert \Vert y \Vert$$
> for some $x,y$ in a Hilbert space. Every proof I found involves some kind of case distinction; namely one may use w.l.o.g $\Vert x \Vert, \Vert y \Vert > 0$ since the inequality is trivial otherwise. However, I was looking for a constructive proof (i.e. without using the law of excluded middle) for the inequality.

For me, a "constructive **proof**" was - in the second i answered the question - "constructive" (as a proof) e.g. in the sense of not avoiding a case by case examination. (One can still construct $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ in the "common sense" with the full system of axioms, and now ask for a "simple", constructive proof of "CS". People working exclusively in constructive mathematics may exclude this interpretation by default, the OP was not really precise at this point. Downvoters can please think about the situation, especially because they live in a world where such distinctions matter. Then reread the question again and again.)

After a first version of this answer was given, we've got in the OP a slightly changed question, there is a pre-Hilbert space instead of a Hilbert space, a general ground field $\Bbb K$ whithout closer specification,
and the "constructive proof" *can* / *may* now be also/rather understood as a valid proof inside constructive analysis. (I would not even have touched the question in that form, if this direction would have been made clear from the beginning, a lot of work. But OK.) Comments have moreover placed the question strictly in the domain of constructive analysis, so the downvotes are more than deserved from this point of view. Now i need to reanswer the question. I will explain the idea from the initial post, that still survives, and put the details in the framework of the constructive analysis. The steps will be to reduce the situation from a general pre-Hilbert space to a pre-Hilbert space with at most two generators,
then to the study of quadratic forms over $\Bbb K$. An alternative "constructive" CS version is given.

---

$(0)$ **Introduction**.

For the reader who never saw this kind of intuitionistic logic, roughly "results are either true, or false, or not known". And we want to study only things that are "constructible" from a sparse set of axioms of the set theory, and propositions that are either true, or false from the same perspective. As an example of something "not known", consider / construct the sequence $a_n$ defined for $n\ge 6$ even by the rule $a_n=0$ if $n$ is the sum of two prime numbers, else $1$. This is well defined, because we can examine "finitely many cases", so we can answer questions like "Is $n$ even?", "Is this special given number $p$ prime?" or "Which are the primes $<n$?" or "Is $n$ the sum of two primes?". However, in order to know if the real number $r=\sum_{n\ge 6\text{ even}}a_n/2^n$ is zero we need a proof for the specific number theoretical conjecture. From this point of view, we have even problems to check if a (constructed) real number is zero or not. Similar examples can be given by taking an other conjecture in number theory to model the "unknown", e.g. $a_n$ is $0$ if there are at least $n$ non-trivial zeros of the Riemann $\zeta$ function, and the $n$.th zero is on the critical line, else $1$. Or one can use Gödel-like settings coming from (un)decidability theory.

But for two rational numbers (and for two numbers in finite algebraic extensions of $\Bbb Q$) we can decide if they are equal or not. Since in $\Bbb Q$ we have again a fraction representation, so a denominator and a bounded interval it lives in, so only finitely many cases to check... (If this kind of mathematics does not feel attractive so far, please do not read further.
This taste of mathematics depends on somebodys own relation to chosen god. If you want to get closer to this entity, reading on will not be completely frustrating, it may be even a good test if somebody likes the fundamental, axiomatic, intuitionistic, and/or logic parts of mathematics. If still here, as a last word of warning, or as a thematic joke, note that after the constructivistic introduction of the set of real numbers $\Bbb R$, the proof that the equality is an equivalence relation on $\Bbb R$ is not a (one-line) joke. So please do not complain about the length of this answer.)

---

$(1)$

Let $X$ be the pre-Hilbert space given in the OP. The ground field is a field $K$ (instead of $\Bbb K$) containing $\Bbb Q$, and a positive cone $K_+$ so that the relations $>$ and $\ge$ can be defined. Fix $x,y\in X$. By considering the vectorial subspace $X'=Kx+Ky$ generated by $x,y$ we may an do assume that $X'$ has dimension $\le 2$ over $K$, and write $X$ instead. (The subspace also comes with a specified set of generators.)

Just as a comment, constructive mathematics makes an issue for the existence of a basis. Links that may serve as a starting point are [mse question 944895](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944895/existence-of-a-basis-in-constructive-vector-spaces), and (for $K=\Bbb Q$) [mo question 326211](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326211/constructivist-defininition-of-linear-subspaces-of-mathbbqn). So in the given generality of the OP ($X$ pre-Hilbert over some $K$), just starting with $X=\Bbb Q^n$ or $X=\Bbb R^n$ or $X=\Bbb C^n$, as vector spaces with a given basis (the canonical basis), is a questionable step that has to be considered in detail. I will also not address here the question, if we can decide, if $X'$ has dimension $0$, $1$, or $2$.

---

$(2)$

In the sequel $a,b$ be scalars in $K$. We have the pre-Hilbert space $X$ over $K$ with generators $x,y\in X$. Then $\langle\ \cdot\ ,\ \cdot\ \rangle$ is a scalar product on $X$ iff it is "*in a classical world*". The OP does not make this precise, i will try to do it below.
Giving $X$ means in particular to give $\|x\|,\|y\|\in K_{\Bbb R}:=K\cap \Bbb R$, with  $\|x\|,\|y\|\ge 0$,
and $\langle x,y\rangle\in K$. An element of $X$ is of the shape $ax+by$ with
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|ax+by\|^2
&=\langle ax+by, ax+by\rangle
\\
&
=
 \langle ax, ax\rangle
+\langle ax, by\rangle
+\langle by, ay\rangle
+\langle by, by\rangle
\\
&
=|a|^2\;\|x\|^2 + 2\text{Real}(ab\langle x, y\rangle) + |b|^2\;\|y\|^2
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
Letting $a,b$ run in $K$, we see that it is necessary and sufficient to insure that the worst case scenario inequality is satisfied:
$$
0\le 
|a|^2\;\|x\|^2 - 2|ab|\; |\langle x, y\rangle| + |b|^2\;\|y\|^2
\ ,\qquad a,b\in K\ .
$$
Equivalently,
$$
0\le 
q(a,b):=
a^2\;\|x\|^2 - 2ab\; |\langle x, y\rangle| + b^2\;\|y\|^2
\ ,\qquad a,b\in K_{\Bbb R, \ \ge 0}\ .
$$
So giving a pre-Hilbert space $X$ over $K$, with generators $x,y\in X$, is equivalent to giving the data:
$$
\|x\|\ge 0\ ,\
\|y\|\ge 0\ ,\
\langle x, y\rangle\in K\ ,\\
q:K_{\Bbb R}\times K_{\Bbb R}\to K_{\Bbb R}\ ,\\
q(a,b)=
a^2\;\|x\|^2 - 2ab\; |\langle x, y\rangle| + b^2\;\|y\|^2\ ,
$$
so that $q\ge 0$. (Terminology: $q$ is non-negative semidefinite form.)
We define the discriminant of the above quadratic form $q$ by $\Delta =4( |\langle x, y\rangle|^2 - \|x\|^2\; \|y\|^2)$. Note that if $\Delta>0$, after possibly passing to a quadratic extension we can construct two distinct "roots" of the associated equation (working to avoid norming problems in the one dimensional projective plane over $K_{\Bbb R}$), and this gives a point where the form $q$ is negative.

But we need the "other direction".

---

$(3)$ Note:

The study of the above quadratic form in $(a,b)$ cannot be "simply replaced" by the study of the form where either $a$ or $b$ is normed to $1$, since the reduction to the cases $\|x\|\ne 0$ and/or $\|y\|\ne 0$ may be problematic in the given framework. But we may get the hint to proceed in this way. (In a "normal" world, if the quadratic form $Ea^2 -2Fab +Gb^2$ with $E,G\ge 0$ is given, we would de-homogenize to get either $Ea^2-2Fa+G$ or $E-2Fb+Gb^2$, then study for a minimal point by inserting either $a=F/E$, and/or $b=F/G$. Without de-homogenization, we have to work "projectively", thus inserting $(a,b)=(F,E)$, and/or $(a,b)=(G,F)$.

---

$(4)$

The given problem is thus equivalent to the following one. We know for the above quadratic form $q$ that $q\ge 0$. (And want to show that the discriminant $\Delta \le 0$ or a related realtion.)
To extract the essence, we start with a non-negative quadratic form of the shape
$$
E\;a^2 -2F\; ab + G\; b^2\ .
$$
In the case of the OP $E,F,G$ are respectively $\|x\|^2$, $|\langle x, y\rangle|$, $\|y\|^2$. Since the values of the quadratic form are always $\ge0$, this is also true for the specializations $(a,b)=(F,E)$, and respectively $(a,b)=(G,F)$, and we obtain:
$$
\begin{aligned}
0&\le E\; F^2 - 2F\; EF + G\; E^2\ ,&\text{i.e. }\qquad 0&\le E(EG-F^2)\ ,\\
0&\le E\; G^2 - 2F\; FG + G\; F^2\ ,&\text{i.e. }\qquad 0&\le G(EG-F^2)\ .\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Adding the two inequalities we obtain:
$$
\begin{aligned}
0&\le (E+G)(EG-F^2)\ ,\qquad\text{ i.e.}\\
\color{blue}{(*)\qquad 0}
&
\color{blue}{\le (\|x\|+\|y\|)(\|x\|\;\|y\|-|\langle x,y\rangle|^2)}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

$(5)$

The above inequality $(*)$ is enough CS for me, and i will no longer bother about getting rid of the $(E+G)$-factor above. (This will be the first point where constructivists will search for an error, so my reaction is to kindly invite them to do this step. One may get rid of this factor in case $K$ is a finite extension of $\Bbb Q$, as comments have teached me. At any rate, this "contorsion" of the CS formula by the factor $(E+G)$ is rather innocent compared to similar contorsions needed to adapt other results from "normal" mathematics to their constructive analysis analogues.)

Comment: Why is the last inequality equivalent to CS? For the equivalence you need $\vert \langle x , y \rangle \vert > 0$ in my opinion.

Comment: If the scalar product of $x$ and $y$ is zero, then CS is obviously satisfied.(Well, in the solution it is not allowed to separate cases, but question on this separation are allowed. How can i answer such questions without going into cases?)

Comment: Well, thats what my question is about. I wonder wether one can show CS without this case distinction.

Comment: So we need a proof for [ Let $a,B\in\Bbb R$, with $B\ge 0$, then $a^2(a^2-B)\le 0$ implies $a^2-B\le 0$ ] only? Ok, here is one without cases. Assume the contrary, namely $a^2-B>0$. Then we have $a^2\le 0$, we also have $-B\le 0$ (given), add and get $a^2-B\le 0$, contradiction. The assumption is false...

Comment: I have one final question: Why is the quadratic form non negative?

Comment: @Diamir The quadratic form takes only values $\ge 0$ because - with the introduced notations - we have in one breath $$0\le \|ax+by\|^2= a^2\|x\|^2 + 2a\text{Real}(b\langle x, y\rangle) + |b|^2\|y\|^2=a^2\|x\|^2 + 2ac|\langle x, y\rangle|^2 + c^2|\langle x, y\rangle|^2\|y\|^2\ .$$ (A copy+paste typo was also corrected in the initial post.)

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I do think there is a issue with your proof, which may be the same issue as the downvoter had in mind. The problem is that while the statement that any rational number is either positive, negative, or zero is constructively valid, it is not valid for real numbers.

Comment: To be able to constructively prove that a real is either positive, negative, or zero you need to give an algorithm that decides which of the three cases is true, but for any Turing machine $T$ you can define a Cauchy sequence \begin{equation} x_n = \begin{cases} 2^{-n} \text{ if } T \text{ does not halt after } n \text{ steps} \\ 2^{-k} \text{ if } T \text{ does halt after } k \le n \text{ steps} \end{cases} \end{equation} This Cauchy sequence converges to $0$ if and only if $T$ does not halt, so deciding whether a given real number is $0$ requires solving the halting problem.

Comment: @qbt937 The answer was rewritten to avoid the kind of a constructive decision needed - as given in the above comment. Thanks a lot for the effort!

Comment: Looks good to me now. +1. I just have a couple small comments, if you're interested in further improving your answer. The final equation mistakenly uses $\|x\|$ and $\|y\|$ instead of $\|x\|^2$ and $\|y\|^2$. In section (2), it took me a while to realize that "we see that it is necessary and sufficient to insure" was referring to the non-negativity of $\|ax+by\|^2$, so that might be worth clarifying. I think the question of removing the $E + G$ factor is interesting, and I'll leave a comment if I come up with anything.

Comment: I think I figured out how to get rid of the $E + G$ factor. It was too long for a comment, so I posted it as an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4240732/206878).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that you can actually prove Cauchy-Schwartz (CS) for an arbitrary inner product space (constructively). In Constructive Analysis by Bishop & Bridges they define inner product spaces so that CS holds:
[image]

However, for the special case of $\mathbb{R}^n$ it is possible to give a constructive proof, which can be found on page 83 of Constructive Analysis:
[image]

Comment: I do not see how this answer addresses the question in the OP. In a first discussion, it "changes the definition" of an inner product space, so that CS is already satisfied, at least cites a book where this change is done, taking this book decision for a kind of an argument that CS *may not* be shown "in a more general situation". In a second discussion, we have a cited "proof by screenshot" in a very special example of a vector space over $\Bbb R$, namely $\Bbb R^n$. This is not even covering the case of a finitely dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$, except we see how to chose a basis.

Comment: @dan_fulea That's the point: you cannot prove Cauchy-Schwarz for an arbitrary inner product space constructively. That's why in Bishop & Bridges they incorporate the Cauchy-Schwarz assumption into the definition. But for the special case of a finite-dimensional inner product space you can prove it constructively, as shown in their book. I don't understand your comment about finite-dimensional inner product spaces: a choice of orthonormal frame is precisely an isometry with $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a completion of dan_fulea's [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2905411/206878).
Where he left off, there is a quadratic form
$$ 0 \le q(x, y) = Ea^2 - 2 F ab + G b^2 , $$
which he evaluated to show that
$$ 0 \le q(F, E) + q(G, F) = (E + G) (E G - F^2) . $$
Here, $E = \|x\|^2$, $F = \vert\langle x, y \rangle\vert$, and $G = \|y\|^2$, so this is equivalent to
$$ 0 \le (\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2) (\|x\|^2 \|y\|^2 - \vert\langle x, y \rangle\vert^2) . $$
This appears to be very close to the desired Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, as the only way for $\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2$ to be zero is if $x = y = 0$, in which case the inequality is trivial.
But it still remains to show this in a constructive way, without assuming $\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 = 0 \lor \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 > 0$.

Instead, evaluate $q(F + G, F + E)$ to find
\begin{align*}
 0
 &\le q(F + G, F + E) \\
 &= E (F + G)^2 - 2 F (F + G) (F + E) + G (F + E)^2 \\
 &= E F^2 + 2 E F G + E G^2 - 2 F^3 - 2 F^2 (E + G) - 2 E F G + F^2 G + 2 E F G + E^2 G \\
 &= E G^2 - 2 F^3 - F^2 (E + G) + 2 E F G + E^2 G \\
 &= E G (E + 2 F + G) - F^2 (E + 2 F + G) \\
 &= (E + 2 F + G) (E G - F^2) .
\end{align*}
Now we'd like to be able to divide both sides by $E + 2 F + G$ to get the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, but this might be dividing by zero.

To work around this issue, use that the reals form a [pseudo-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-order).
In particular, the reals satisfy the comparison property,
$$ a < b \implies a < c \lor c < b . $$
Now for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have $\epsilon < 2 \epsilon$, so $\epsilon < E + 2 F + G \lor E + 2 F + G < 2 \epsilon$.
In the former case, we have bounded $E + 2 F + G$ away from zero, so after dividing $q(F + G, F + E)$ by it we get $E G - F^2 \ge 0 \ge -\epsilon^2$.
In the latter case, we have
\begin{align*}
 2 F &\le 2 \epsilon \\
 -F^2 &\ge -\epsilon^2 \\
 E G - F^2 &\ge -\epsilon^2 .
\end{align*}
This shows that $E G - F^2 \ge -\epsilon^2$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.
Since $\le$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can apply $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}$ to both sides of the inequality to get $E G - F^2 \ge 0$, i.e. $\|x\|^2 \|y\|^2 \ge \vert\langle x, y \rangle\vert^2$.
Taking the square root of both sides then gives the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a proof from Pugh, Real Mathematical Analysis. I don't know if this proof can be modified for a complex vector space, but in case you're working over $\Bbb{R}$ it may be what you're looking for.

Let $x$ and $y$ be arbitrary and let $w = x + ty$ for a scalar $t$. Define $Q(t) = \langle w, w \rangle=\langle x + ty, x + ty \rangle$.

Then $Q(t)$ is nonnegative, being the value of an inner product. By the bilinearity of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$, we have:
$$ Q(t) = \langle x,x\rangle + 2t\langle x,y \rangle + t^2\langle y,y\rangle = c + bt + at^2$$

Interpret $Q$ as a parabola; since it is nonnegative its discriminant $b^2 - 4ac$ must be nonpositive (else there would be two real roots, thus a segment of the parabola below the real axis). This gives:
$$ 4\langle x,y\rangle^2-4\langle x, x\rangle \langle y,y\rangle \leq 0,$$ or rewriting:
$$ \langle x,y \rangle^2 \leq \langle x,x\rangle \langle y,y \rangle. $$
Taking the square root of both sides gives the result.

Comment: Just to be super-picky: when you say "interpret $Q$ as a parabola" you are assuming $\langle y,y\rangle\neq 0$. Well, unless you allow degenerate parabolas but then you shouldn't mention two roots later and it is just moving the dreaded "case distinction" elsewhere. Just saying... :))

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's true. Pugh completely ignores the possibility; in the case that $\langle y,y\rangle=0$, then actually $y=0$ so $Q$ is a constant function. Is this what the original question is trying to avoid, then?

Comment: I'm not sure. It is a bit of an academic discussion.

Comment: This case distinction is unfortunately  not allowed. This would only work when one allows the law of excluded middle.

Answer (score -2):

Breaking into cases doesn't necessarily rely on the law of excluded middle. It is true in a Hilbert space that either $x = 0$ or $x \neq 0$, we don't need to appeal to excluded middle for this fact. This constructively/intuitionistically reduces the problem to finding a proof for both the case $x=0$ and the case $x \neq 0$.

In other words, I agree that a case analysis uses excluded middle in some sense, but if you can constructively prove excluded middle for the cases you are considering, then you don't need to assume it in general.

Comment: Wikipedia seems to suggest that according to the 'intuitionist' (constructivist) point of view, one cannot accept the assertion that every element in an inner product space is either zero or nonzero, if said space is infinite. But what the heck else could it be??

Comment: @dbx The point is that in constructive mathematics saying $P\lor Q$ means you have a witness for $P$ or you have a witness for $Q$ *and you know which you have*. At an intuitive level, if someone gives me a real number which I think might be $0$, I can never convince myself of it. No matter how many digits I check, it could always be the case that a non-$0$ digit could occur. Of course, if I know how that number was produced, I might be able to convince myself that it must produce $0$.

Comment: @dbx More formally, for any Turing machine it is easy to make a real number that is $0$ if and only if the Turing machine halts. Therefore, being able to know whether or not a real number is $0$ is equivalent to being able to solve the Halting Problem. It is compatible with constructive logic to assume that all witnesses are computable, so $\forall x\in\mathbb R.x=0\lor\neg(x=0)$ has no witness since it would be uncomputable. For other, anti-classical systems such as synthetic differential geometry, there really is "extra" stuff. In SDG, $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x^2=0\}$ is distinct from $\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I'm hesitant to continue the discussion, because I think that's not what comments are for. But I would point out that in this case our setting is an *arbitrary* Hilbert space rather than $\Bbb{R}$. I think that once we accept the abstraction of working in a general space, practical considerations such as decimal expansions go by the wayside, and an insistence on particular witnesses seems contradictory.

Comment: @dbx I was simply providing examples of how its possible for $\forall x.x=0\lor x\neq 0$ can fail constructively. That said, if the theorem fails for a particular example, it's certainly not going to provable in general.

Comment: Either $x = 0$ or $x \neq 0$ is not constructive, for the proof of this one has to use the law of excluded middle.